# Check if Object is Empty in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I need to check whether the status is approved or not, so i check it if it is empty. Whats the most efficient way to do this?

**RESPONSE**

```
 {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "yeah@yahoo.com",
      "approved": {
        "approved_at": "2020"
      },
      "verified": {
        "verified_at": "2020"
      }
    }
```

**CODE**

```
    const checkIfEmpty = (user) => {
    if (Object.entries(user.verified).length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this way

```js
const checkIfVerifiedExists = (user) => {
    if (user && user.verified && Object.keys(user.verified).length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists(null));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({something: "a"}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: null}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: ""}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: "a"}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: "a", something: "b"}));
```

Or More simple You can use **Ternary Operator**

```js
const checkIfVerifiedExists = (user) => {
    return (user && user.verified && Object.keys(user.verified).length) ? true : false
};

console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists(null));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({something: "a"}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: null}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: ""}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: "a"}));
console.log(checkIfVerifiedExists({verified: "a", something: "b"}));
```

Comment: I think you don't need Ternary Operator there, It will reture boolean anyway.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that user.verified is an object based on JSON schema

```
const checkIfEmpty = (user) => {
    return !!(user && user.verified);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try it:

```js
const isEmpty = (obj) => {
    for(let key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and use:

```js
if(isEmpty(user)) {
    // user is empty
} else {
    // user is NOT empty
}
```